# Rails Advanced Sorting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, sorting, activerecord

I have three models, basically:

```
class Vendor
  has_many :items
end

class Item
  has_many :sale_items
  belongs_to :vendor
end

class SaleItem
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Essentially, each `sale_item` points to a specific `item` (but has an associated quantity and sale price which might be different from the `item`'s base price, hence the separate model), and each `item` is made by a specific `vendor`.

I'd like to sort all `sale_item`s by vendor name, but this means going through the associated `item`, because that's where the association is.

My first attempt was to change `SaleItem` to the following:

```
class SaleItem
  belongs_to :item
  has_one :vendor, :through => :item
end
```

Which allows me to look for `SaleItem.first.vendor`, but doesn't allow me to do something like:

```
SaleItem.joins(:vendor).all(:order => "vendors.name")
```

Is there an easy way to figure out these complex associations and sorting? It would be especially great if there were a plugin that could take care of these sort of things. I have a lot of different types of tables to add sorting to in this application, and I feel like this will be a big chunk of the figuring-out work.

Comment: So you just want to sort your items by assoicated vendors?

Comment: SaleItems have a foreign key column (sale_items.item_id) tied to items.id, and Items have a foreign key column (items.vendor_id) tied to vendors.id. I want to sort SaleItems by the vendor associated with their associated item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could definitely be done with a more complex SQL query (possibly using `find_by_sql`), but you could also do it pretty easily in Ruby. Try something like the following:

```
SaleItem.find(:all, :include => { :items => :vendors }).sort do |first,second|
  first.vendor.name <=> second.vendor.name
end
```

I haven't tested it, so it might not work exactly like this, but it should give you a good idea of one possible solution.

**Edit**: Found an old blog post that seems to have solved this issue. Hopefully this still works in the lastest version of ActiveRecord.

source: http://matthewman.net/2007/01/04/eager-loading-objects-in-a-rails-has_many-through-association/

**Second Edit**: Straight from the Rails documentation

> To include a deep hierarchy of associations, use a hash:
>
> `for post in Post.find(:all, :include => [ :author, { :comments => { :author => :gravatar } } ])`
>
> That’ll grab not only all the comments but all their authors and gravatar pictures. You can mix and match symbols, arrays and hashes in any combination to describe the associations you want to load.

There's your explanation.

Comment: I attempted to do something like this, but there is no `vendor_id` column in `sale_items`. The database would need to look at the `item_id` column in `sale_items`, then in the `items` table, look at the item's `vendor_id` column, and get the `name` value from the associated vendor.

Comment: Answer has been edited with a possible solution. Sorry I can't check it myself here at work.

Comment: That's it! I don't know how I spent so long searching and never found that. Where in the documentation is it?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html under "Eager loading of associations"

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need your sale_items sorted by the database, or could you wait until it is presented and do the sorting client side via javascript (there are some great sorting libraries out there) - that would save server CPU and (backend) code complexity.

Comment: I would like to sort on the server, because these items will also be paginated, and I don't want to have to load the entire set of data if it is not going to be displayed.